# gradle: importing local bom

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies

We have a multi-module project with all dependency versions listed in the top-level `pom.xml`. Is there any way to make Gradle use it, without having to install this bom into local maven repo?

More specifically: there's a `pom.xml` listing all dependencies in the `<dependencyManagement>` section. Gradle build uses `"io.spring.dependency-management"` plugin's `importBom` to read it from the `mavenLocal()`. This works, but requires an extra step:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=pom.xml -DpomFile=pom.xml
```

which publishes the bom to the local maven repository where gradle can find it. Is there any way to avoid it? Ideally I'd like to have something like this:

```
dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom "./pom.xml"
  }
}
```

..which of course is not a valid "string module notation". Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK it's impossible to import plain file, you need to install it previously and specify the whole artifact.

Comment: any way this can be automated? Can gradle perform `install:install-file` on it's own? `maven-publish` and `publishToMavenLocal` may be, but without `pom.xml` generation?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: [nebula-recommender-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-dependency-recommender-plugin) allows import pom files directly:

```
dependencyRecommendations {
  mavenBom file: file('pom.xml')
}
```